# SQL Server procedure to duplicate structure and data of a whole database into another

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, business-intelligence

We have an application with a big database running at our service provider. They provided us a tool to import the database into our own to do some BI (with Jet Reports) on it. But when running that tool the database is dropped and recreated. This breaks the BI-part: Jet Reports thinks it is a whole new database.

Also, the structure of the database changes without a notification. So a column can be added or removed, without us knowing it.

That being said, do you know how to create a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 which first matches the structure with a "staging" database and after that imports all data from the original database.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the source database?
What you can do is create a publication so that it is linked from one base to another

Comment: No, we don't have direct access. We have been provided a tool to "sync" the data, but what it does is drop the database on-premise and recreate and fill it with data.

Comment: @JohandeHaan: try to make the imported database as staging one,by checking with them